# Android Uri Builder

Tags: android

How to Build Uri for Following URL
Stuck to add , in code

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?zip=281121,in&APPID=40c33efe4ed1e3032b20edfba14b3c56

my code:

```
public class NetworkUtils {
public static URL BuildUri(String ZIPCODE){
    URL url = null;
             String zip = "zip";
                final String Country = ",in";
             String APPID = "APPID";
    final String forecast_base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
    Uri builtURI = Uri.parse(forecast_base_url)
            .buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(zip,ZIPCODE+Country)
            .appendQueryParameter(APPID,"40c33efe4ed1e3032b20edfba14b3c56").build();

    try {
         url = new URL(builtURI.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return url;
}
```

Comment: You need to at least mention what you tried. You are asking about a very broad topic. Read what this API is based on, whether XML or JSON, then read how to scrape the result and get the output you desire.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you build it, the Uri gets encoded using the UTF-8 scheme.

So you can decode it like this:

```
URL myUrl = new URL(URLDecoder.decode(builtURI.toString(), "UTF-8"));
```

Or like this:

```
URL myUrl = new URL(Uri.decode(builtURI.toString()));
```

(You will need to try-catch this)

Little more on Uri encoding:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: that i know Sir i jst wanna ask  zip = 281121,in this ",in" which parameter is used to pass this in Uri i tried by manually giving this with (zip + ",in") but its not working

Comment: Please, post what you've tried in your original post.

Comment: Thank you Sir it worked can you Please Explain the ABove piece of code what u did

Comment: Sure. This happens because when you build it, the Uri gets encoded using the UTF-8 scheme. 

I have update my answer.
mark it as correct if you feel like it.